# Disabling over-eager Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I've got a Visual Studio 2017 solution generated by CMake.

When I'm trying to edit the CMakeLists.txt file in Visual Studio 2017, I get a bunch of completion popups constantly popping up as I type. (This happens even in comments.) I keep having to press escape to dismiss them so that I can use the cursor keys, which is getting a bit tiresome.

I've unticked all the `Statement completion` options for all languages in the options... but still they come.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: That's coming from some extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be due to the Visual Studio Extension for TextMate Grammars.

(This extension doesn't appear to have any options, but it seems to do something to the handling of text files, especially when dragged and dropped onto Visual Studio from Explorer.)